# Microsoft.Graph.Core Code:accessDenied uploading file to One Drive API

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I use the below code to upload the file to OneDrive API.

```
var uploadedFile = await requestBuilder
                              .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                              .Content
                              .Request()
                              .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
```

When requestBuilder is one of the following:

```
requestBuilder = graphClient.Sites[ids.siteId].Drive.Root;
requestBuilder = graphClient.Sites[ids.siteId].Drive.Items[ids.folderId];
```

It fails with the error below:

[image]

When I use requestBuilder as the following, it works fine:

```
requestBuilder = graphClient.Me.Drive.Root;
```

This code works fine for my companies Azure setup, but when I've had a customer create their Azure App, and have checked that it matches my setup; they are getting the error above.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions. If you call the following endpoint

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content

var uploadedFile = await graphClient.Sites[ids.siteId].Drive.Root
                          .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                          .Content
                          .Request()
                          .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
```

`Sites.ReadWrite.All` permission is required.